# Update given field value with every fetch request in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have a simple [Strapi](https://strapi.io)-backed CMS with a **post** content type. This document (content type) has fields like **title**, **secondary title**, **excerpt**, **body**, etc. Now I want to be able to record view counts for each entry in this document.

So, I have added to it a number field called **views** with 0 as its default value. Following instructions in the Strapi documentation, I added the following code to my api model (at `/api/post/models/Post.js`):

```
beforeFetchAll: async (model) => {
  model.views += 1;
},
```

I understand any snippet inside of the `beforeFetch` method ought to trigger and execute before any `fetch` operation which is what the `post` query does in GraphQL. However, despite several fetches, the value in this field stays unchanged. Any Strapi dev who could give an idea where I'm going wrong?
The full code can be found at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/dev/api/post/models/Post.js.

**P.S.**: The query I'm attempting to execute in GraphQL Playground at https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql is:

```
{
  posts(limit: 1, where: {slug: "one-post"}) {
    id
    title
    views
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that I suggest you understand this concept https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#backend-customization

Then you will have to customize the findOne controller function of the Post API.

Here you will find the default function to udpate. https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#controllers

Here what it will should look like:

**Path —** `./api/post/controller/Post.js`

```js
  async findOne(ctx) {
    const entity = await strapi.services.post.findOne(ctx.params);

    const sanitized = sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.post });

    const newView = sanitized.views + 1;
    strapi.query('post').update({ id: sanitized.id }, {
      views: newView
    });

    return sanitized;
  },
```

Here a short video to help https://www.loom.com/share/df0cb65c52b0478d994c3732fac84020